# Arraylist equals always returns true

Tags: java

My goal is to make a 2D boardgame version of Slenderman, but I'm having trouble with the equals and the hashCode methods.

Here I have an Arraylist of obstacles (x and y coordinates, the player cannot step on) and I also want to generate an another Arraylist which will consist of the coordinates, where I can put papers. *(In the game the player has to find these papers in order to win.)*
I'm trying to make the paperList by checking the surroundings of that particular position, since there shouldn't be any papers on the board, the player can't reach.

My exact problem is, that this for-cycle puts ALL obstacle positions in the paperList and I cannot figure out why.

```
for (Position p : obstacleList) {
            Position p1 = new Position (p.x - 46, p.y);
            Position p2 = new Position (p.x + 46, p.y);
            Position p3 = new Position (p.x, p.y - 46);
            Position p4 = new Position (p.x, p.y + 46);

            label :
            {
                if (obstacleList.contains(p1) && obstacleList.contains(p2) && obstacleList.contains(p3) && obstacleList.contains(p4)) {
                    break label;
                } else if (p1.x < 0 && obstacleList.contains(p3) && obstacleList.contains(p4)) {
                    break label;
                } else if (p2.x > WIDTH && obstacleList.contains(p3) && obstacleList.contains(p4)) {
                    break label;
                } else if (p3.y < 0 && obstacleList.contains(p1) && obstacleList.contains(p2)) {
                    break label;
                } else if (p4.y > HEIGHT && obstacleList.contains(p1) && obstacleList.contains(p2)) {
                    break label;
                } else paperList.add(p);
            }
        }
```

```
public class Position{
    public int x;
    public int y;

@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Position)) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        if (obj == this) return true;

        Position position= (Position) obj;
        return x == position.x && y == position.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you step through your code with a debugger already?

Comment: how could i know why is always going on <else>. I don't know what's in obstacleList. Very hard to help you. Don't have all the necessary information...

Comment: Just to be clear - is your intention that the paper list should contain the coordinates of all the obstacles that are *not* surrounded by 4 other obstacles? (and assuming that the edge acts like an obstacle?)

Comment: From the code you posted, it looks like you can simply remove the `label` label and also remove all the `break label;` statements. An `if` block can be empty.

Comment: This actually looks like it should work to me, at least for ones not at the edges. I don't think the edge code is right though. Can you post some more code indicating how you call it? (I agree implementation could be better as Abra says)

Comment: Thank you Abra and Peter! I removed the label and it seems to be working. The edges seem fine, except one... I'm still working on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `break label;` statement is not breaking out of your loop. To do that, you need to *label your loop* by moving the `label:` to just before the `for` statement.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I removed the label completely, now it works fine.

Comment: If you removed the label completely, then that wasn't what this answer suggested. I'd be interested to see what you did actually do to make it work correctly!

Comment: @PeterHull removing the label completely (therefore using `break;` instead of `break label;` with label being just before the `for` statement) has exactly the same effect, because the simple `break;` statement would apply to the nearest enclosing loop, i.e. the `for` loop. Alternatively, the OP could also just put a null statement "`;`" instead of break.